# WCF serialization error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have method of a WCF service that accepts an interface as a parameter called IClient

```
[OperationContract]
void RegisterClientToCallBackTo(IClientCallBack client);

public interface IClient
{
    void SendMessage(string message);
}
```

I have a windows form that implements iclient and When I pass the form into the method I get the error:
Type 'FormMain' cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute.  Consider marking the base type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute, or removing them from the derived type.

i tried marking the form with [DataContractAttribute] and [SerializableAttribute] but i still get that same error

any ideas?

Comment: Can you include the calling the serialization (and the serialization code)?

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't pass a form via WCF; WCF is intended to pass *state*, not implementation. IMO, you would be best served by creating a DTO to represent the *data* you want to pass, and pass *that* via WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the definition of SendMessage.

Also you need to make sure that you update the client reference, whenever you change the contract or service.

**EDIT**

As others have noted you must send a DTO you cannot send a form.

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you that you can't just mark the subclass (i.e. your Form) with [DataContractAttribute] and [SerializableAttribute], you have to mark all parent classes with [DataContractAttribute] and [SerializableAttribute] as well.  You'll need to find another way.

It seems odd to be passing a form, anyway - it doesn't sound like good encapsulation to have a form managing contact with a service.  Maybe it's time to look at a [presentation pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) like [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter)?  Your callback would then be in a class under your control.